# Why is there >>>>>>> in my code after a git merge, the code doesn't compile anymore

Tags: git, github

New to git, can someone tell me how git tags work and how to not include them when you clone the repo? --no-tag option doesn't work, and I get something like this when cloned. Obviously, due to this, code doesn't compile, how to remove all of this or clone without including such tags?

```
//private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeRepository.class);
>>>>>>> 6c8a76ce2d2a290c4b0409cadfbfafcee5d55c13
```

Comment: That is not a tag.  It's the result of a borked merge-conflict resolution.

Comment: can u also tell me how to resolve it? and how it occurs?

Answer (score 0):

You problem is not a tag problem. What happens to your git is that a merge-conflict happens. It means that the files on the git aren't the same with the ones on your local machine.
Here is the official solving method from github : https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/